# ldapsearch doesn't return results when using userPrincipleName as filter?

Tags: ldap, ldap-query, freeipa

I have a running freeipa ldap server that I am using for user management. I need to search for users using userPrincipleName attribute. I can search using uid filter as follows:

`ldapsearch -H "ldap://ldap.domain.net" -D "uid=badr,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=domain,dc=net" -w "password" -b "uid=badr,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=domain,dc=net" "uid=badr"`

But, when I change the filter to `userPrincipleName`, it returns nothing.

`ldapsearch -H "ldap://ldap.domain.net" -D "uid=badr,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=domain,dc=net" -w "password" -b "uid=badr,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=domain,dc=net" "userPrincipleName=badr@domain.net"`

I suspect that something has to be done on ldap server in order for it to work correctly.

Where could the mistake be here?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FreeIPA does not have attribute type *userPrincipleName* in its schema.

Furthermore the attribute *userPrincipalName*, defined in MS AD, is spelled differently but is also not in FreeIPA's schema.

Instead FreeIPA user entries contain the attribute *krbPrincipalName* defined in LDAP schema for MIT Kerberos.

In case a client application is only capable of using *userPrincipalName* for searching one could setup a LDAP proxy based on OpenLDAP's [LDAP backend](https://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapd-ldap) with [slapo-rwm](https://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapo-rwm) implementing the attribute mapping.

Comment: Could you please suggest another ldap server that supports this attribute userPrincipalName? I need that in order to get some service, which only searches using that attribute, to able to search in ldap server.

Comment: Something else, what about this? 
https://www.freeipa.org/page/V4/Support_of_UPN_for_trusted_domains

Comment: I've edited my answer: LDAP proxy for attribute mapping